# MySQL SELECT .. WHERE .. ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1000000,10 performance

Tags: mysql, index, query-performance

I have following Innodb table with ~2.500.000 rows:

`ID | param1 | param2 | param3 | param4 | sort_field1 | sort_field2 | sort_field3 | sort_field4`

```
ID - int, PK
param1-4 - tinyint(1), INDEX (it has only 0 OR 1 value)
sort_field1-4 - int, INDEX (it could be any number in INT range)
```

Each param(1-4) has value distrubution about 40% of 0 and 60% of 1.

I am trying to optimize fetching rows from the middle-end of table in this super simple query:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE param1=0 ORDER BY sort_field1 LIMIT 1000000,10
```

It took about 1.7sec to fetch 10 rows and EXPLAIN show that only param1 index is being used.

I can create index (param1,sort_field1) and it will reduce time to 0.17sec, but i can't create indexes for each and every combination of params and sort_field.

Is it possible to optimize this query and/or table to achieve time similar to one i got with combined index?

Comment: `… and EXPLAIN show that …` - you should include the output of `EXPLAIN` in case there is something else in there that would offer clues.

Comment: Also it looks like you are trying to avoid the EAV or "property bag" anti-pattern by implementing another, but it is not clear from the column names what your columns actually represent. Perhaps `id (int), param (int, 1-4), paramvalue (tinyint), paramsort` with `id,param` as the PK then an index on `param,paramvalue,paramsort` will cover all four (and more if you add them later).

Comment: I agree with David -- Please tell us what you are doing and why you need to reach far into the table.  We may be able to suggest another way to solve the problem.  (`OFFSET` is implemented by counting past that many rows, hence taking a long time even with an index.)